# Transformation gets slow while groupBy in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive

I am new to spark , I am having one table contains 100 cr of data in table.
Table Schema are:

> id **int**
>   name **varchar**
>   dept_id **int**
>   salary **double**

I am doing group by operation and doing sum of salary in particular group.

For that i have write below code :

```
val empData = sqlContext.sql("Select id ,name, dept_id , salary from emp")

val empData_map = empData.map(row => {
      Row(row.getInt(0), row.getString(1), row.getInt(2), row.getDouble(3))
    })

val finalResult =  empData_map.map({ final_data => 
      ((final_data.getInt(0), final_data.getString(1), final_data.getInt(2)), final_data.getDouble(3))
    }).reduceByKey((x, y) =>((x._1 + y._1)))
```

But my question is , But Performance is slow by using this. Can anyone suggest me, Wheather i am using correct transformation technique or not.

Do you have any other option(Fast) for this type of transformation.

**Note: Syntax may be wrong.**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not sure why you're putting things into a `Row` and then out again. Also, I would recommend datasets.

Comment: @Reactormonk So can you please help me out, How can I do this type of transformation using data set.

Comment: Which Spark version?

Comment: Spark 1.4.1 version

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
val session = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("reader").getOrCreate;
val df = session.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").option("mode", "DROPMALFORMED").load("data");

df.createOrReplaceTempView("people")

val dept_sum=spark.sql("select dept_id,sum(salary) from people group by dept_id")
```